# В списке каждый элемент надо вывести задом наперёд, но в конце всегда ставится точка или знак вопроса и он должен остаться на месте

Tags: python, list

В списке каждый элемент надо вывести задом наперёд, но в конце всегда ставится точка или знак вопроса и он должен остаться на месте
Например: "Я хочу!" должно вывести Я учох!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А где ваш код? Код - в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

1. получить новую строку, отрезав последний символ через `[:-1]`
2. разбить новую строку на слова через `split()`
3. перевернуть слова через `[::-1]`
4. склеить слова через `join()`
5. добавить последний символ в новую строку
6. потратить 1 час и подучить базу питона